# Using PHPStorm's Built-In Git Functionality - Do I Need To Initialize Git on My Local Machine?

Tags: phpstorm

I just added Git onto a project on a remote Amazon EC2 server.  Before this, I was using PHPStorm's deployment -> sync-to functionality to upload any changes on my local machine to the Amazon instance.

Right now, I have a .git folder on the remote box that has all the files on that box committed to it.  On my local machine, I have not setup Git for this particular project.

Do I need to setup a .git instance outside of PHPStorm and through the command line before I can connect my local repository to the remote repository?  I went through this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLwseyjzmdI) from JetBrains.  On the initial setup steps when you go to "VCS"->"Checkout from version control"->"Git", the presenter chooses a local directory to "create" the Git project inside of PHPStorm.  I tried substiuting the local directory with my remote server's address and received an error.

Comment: not sure I follow you. How do you suppose to connect local repository to remote one fi you don't have a local repository at all? Cloning remote repository to create a local copy seems logical, doesn't it?

Comment: @lena I think the gest of my question is whether PHPStorm will automatically set up a local repository on your machine if you give it the remote URL

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into this myself. By default, when you do File -> New Project from Existing Files then use "Web server is on remote host, files are accessible via FTP/SFTP/FTPS", all .git files are ignored. Go into your Deployment options, and remove .git from this list of ignored filetypes. Now, when you create a New Project from Existing Files, the .git files will also be included. PhpStorm will then know that the project is Gitified and you'll have your functionality.

Comment: Also note that if you attempt to do git commands on the remote host, and you get errors due to git repo corruption (e.g. `git status` results in "fatal: bad object HEAD"), you are probably missing git objects from your local machine. For some reason, I find it occasionally necessary to do a manual sync with local to remote in the Remote Host view of PHPStorm.